# Assemble the data through JS Map

Tags: javascript

code1:

```
let commap = new Map();
    data.forEach(function(item,index){
        if(commap.has(item.comp)){
            let arr = companyset.get(item.comp);
            arr.push(item);
            commap.set(item.comp,arr);
        }else{
            commap.set(item.comp,[item]);
        }
    });
```

code2:

```
let commap = new Map();
    data.forEach(function(item,index){
        commap .set(item.comp,commap.has(item.comp)?commap.get(item.comp).push(item):[item]);
    });
```

The logic of the two pieces of code is the same, if there is more than one entry for company,code2 throw an error:'Uncaught TypeError: commap.get(...).push is not a function',
why did this error occur,is it the order of js execution?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `.push` returns the *new length* of the array, not the array itself. So, when you `set` the value to `companyset.get(item.company).push(item)`, you're setting the value to a *number*, not an *array*, which means when you try to `push` to it later, an error is thrown.

Remember that arrays, being non-primitive, can be changed simply with a reference to the array, without having to re-assign it. You only have to `set` the first time you come across a new `company`. Try something like this instead:

```js
const data = [
  { company: 'foo' },
  { company: 'bar' },
  { company: 'foo' },
  { company: 'foo' },
];
const companyset = new Map();
data.forEach(function(item) {
  const { company } = item;
  const arr = companyset.get(company);
  if (!arr) return companyset.set(company, [item]);
  arr.push(item);
});
console.log(companyset.get('foo'));
```

But to combine an array into an object, it would be more appropriate to use `reduce` instead of `forEach`:

```js
const data = [
  { company: 'foo' },
  { company: 'bar' },
  { company: 'foo' },
  { company: 'foo' },
];
const companyset = data.reduce((map, item) => {
  const { company } = item;
  const arr = map.get(company);
  if (!arr) map.set(company, [item]);
  else arr.push(item);
  return map;
}, new Map());
console.log(companyset.get('foo'))
```